# Efficiency issue with closure based objects

Tags: javascript, prototype, closures

One way to define a class in Javascript is with closures and the object literal. As an example, consider a circle:

```
var circle = function(radius) {
    var radius = radius;
    return {
        area: function() { 
            return Math.PI*(radius*radius); 
        }
    }
}
```

Circle objects can then be instantiated with the internal variables remaining encapsulated:

```
c = circle(1);
c.area(); // Returns pi
c.radius; // Returns undefined
```

Unfortunately with this method, if I was to create multiple circles the area function would be copied for each instance. This is where the prototyping is usually used:

```
var Circle = function(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}
Circle.prototype.area = function() { 
    return Math.PI*(this.radius*this.radius); 
};
```

Now the problem is that variables cannot be declared private:

```
c = new Circle(1); 
c.area(); // Returns pi 
c.radius; // Returns 1
```

Does anyone know how I would get the best of both? Efficiency is an issue so would rather avoid the current formulation of the first method, and I am writing for a public API so don't want users to have access to internal variables/methods. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function Circle(radius) {
    this.getRadius = function() { return radius; }
}

Circle.prototype.area = function() {
    var r = this.getRadius();
    return Math.PI * r * r; 
};
```

Now each instance of the `Circle` pseudo-class has two methods:

- `area` which is inherited from the prototype thus making it a public method
- `getRadius` which is assigned to the instance object thus making it an instance method

The `radius` value is still retrievable via `getRadius` though. However, if `getRadius` could determine whether it's called from within a `Circle.prototype` method and only return the `radius` value if it is, then that would solve it, but I'm not sure that that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, though whether creating the GetArea() method everytime is "efficient" I doubt, but it's the only way I'm aware of to access the a local scope variable from prototype methods:

```
var Circle = (function(){
    var Circle = function(radius) {
        this.GetRadius = function(){
            return radius;
        }
    };
    Circle.prototype.area = function() {
        var rad = this.GetRadius();
        return Math.PI*(rad*rad); 
    };
    return function(radius){
        return new Circle(radius);
    }
})();
```

(This will allow access to the value of the Radius of the circle, but not allow you to change it, which is why I presume you wanted this)

Comment: Essentially the same implmentation as Šime Vidas' answer, but using factory design pattern, which you could skip if you want, I just tend to use it for all most of my "classes" at the moment